# How can I reload a variable in flask context processor?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask server and I have a layout.html that other templates inherit. layout.html has a variable `var initContent = {{initContent|tojson}}` that is the content of init.py file. If init.py has changed, how can I change `initContent` without refreshing/reloading the page?

This is in flask_server.py :

```
@app.context_processor 
def load_file():

    f = open(os.getcwd()+"/init.py", 'r')
    initContent = f.read()
    print(initContent)
    f.close()

    return {"initContent":initContent}

app.context_processor(load_file)
```

Any comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. If the init.py change on the server, you want the client's page to change automatically? Without refreshing?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to change `initContent` and modify the client's page without refreshing.

Comment: It is not, at least as is. When Flask responds to the client, the connection ends. You could use ajax and have the client check the server every x seconds or minutes. Then if there's a change you get it that way, and can then update the content on the page without refreshing the page.